# Cyrillic alphabet in help function from Python 3 don't work in Powershell Windows 10

Tags: python, powershell, encoding, code-documentation

I have this function:

```
def decomposition():
    """
        Вызов модуля oval_decomposition.py для разложения OVAL xml на
        составные части - определения, объекты и т.д.

        Для корректного сбора модулем build необходима следующая секция
        внутри каждого <definition>:
        <oval_repository>
            <dates>
                <submitted date="YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000+00:00">
                    <contributor organization="ORGANISATION">JOHN WICK</contributor>
                </submitted>
            </dates>
        </oval_repository>

    """
    oval_decomposition.main()
```

And this is what i get in Powershell, when i use help(decomposition):

> ```
> ┬√чют ьюфєы  oval_decomposition.py фы  Ёрчыюцхэш  OVAL xml эр
> ёюёЄртэ√х ўрёЄш - юяЁхфхыхэш , юс·хъЄ√ ш Є.ф.
>
> ─ы  ъюЁЁхъЄэюую ёсюЁр ьюфєыхь build эхюсїюфшьр ёыхфє■∙р  ёхъЎш 
> тэєЄЁш ърцфюую <definition>:
> <oval_repository>
>     <dates>
>         <submitted date="YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000+00:00">
>             <contributor organization="ORGANISATION">JOHN WICK</contributor>
>         </submitted>
>     </dates>
> </oval_repository>
> ```

When i use Cyrillic alphabet in print it works. It also works normally in Linux when i add "# coding: utf-8" in the beginning of file. However, this does not help in Windows. I also tried this to change Powershell encoding:

```
PS C:\Users\denis\Documents\dev\OVALRepo> "$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8"
System.Text.UTF8Encoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8
```

I can't find methods to change help function encoding manually like we can do in print function.

Comment: I tried also [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("utf-8") and [Console]::OutputEncoding=[Text.Encoding]::UTF8, both actually change encoding in Properties of PS, but no effects on code...

Comment: `[Console]::InputEncoding =  [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1251)` works for me if I set _Language for non-Unicode programs_ to `Russian (Russia)` in _Administrative language settings_

Comment: It's actually worked! No idea why Python print() works without that or why PowerShell does not use unicode by default so apps like Python could stop guessing encoding. Is there a way to make it all work in unicode?

Comment: Sorry, I'm _not_ ready to read source code of Python's built-in functions 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved definitely after applying [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/) rigorously in Windows.

Tried using different alphabet combination (Latin, Cyrillic and Greek scripts) as follows: `type .\testHelp.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def foo():
    """
    help in Czech, Greek, Russian
    nápověda česky, řecky, rusky
    βοήθεια στα Τσεχικά, Ελληνικά, Ρωσικά (¹)
    помощь на чешском, греческом, русском языках (¹)
    (¹) from Google Translate
    """
    return ''

help(foo)
```

**Result** if run from pure `cmd` or from `PowerShell` (version 5.1) or from `pwsh` (version 7):

```
python .\testHelp.py
```

> ```
> Help on function foo in module __main__:
>
> foo()
>     help in Czech, Greek, Russian
>     nápověda česky, řecky, rusky
>     βοήθεια στα Τσεχικά, Ελληνικά, Ρωσικά (¹)
>     помощь на чешском, греческом, русском языках (¹)
>     (¹) from Google Translate
> ```

(**or** `Copy&Paste` the above code in an open `python` prompt).

**Settings**:

- Set *Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support* in [Administrative language settings](https://superuser.com/q/1033088/376602):

[image: Language for non-Unicode programs]

**Addendum**: You met a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case; for instance, `Вызов` (the 1st word in your example) is shown as `┬√чют` due to the following mojibake mechanism:

```
>>> 'Вызов'.encode('cp1251').decode('cp866') == '┬√чют'
True
>>> 'Вызов' == '┬√чют'.encode('cp866').decode('cp1251')
True
```